# javac cant find symbol (method)

Tags: java, cmd, command-prompt

so I decided to learn how to program. I started using an old book on how to program. i used the disc to install JDK 3.something and started reading. the first thing it has you program is a sample, similar to "hello world"

this is what I have, i typed it exactly how the book said to:

```
 //My first java program

public class cooljava {

    public static void main (String args[])
    {
        System.out.print1n("Java is Cool");
    }
}
```

this is what i typed in command prompt:

```
c:\Users\johns_000\My Documents>javac cooljava.java
```

the path is completely correct.

this is what it said

```
cooljava.java:7: cannot find symbol
symbol  : method print1n(java.lang.String)
location: class java.io.PrintStream
                System.out.print1n("Java is Cool");
                          ^
1 error
```

and thats it. please help. i dont want to continue until i can get this to work. P.S. i'm using windows 8. Thanks!

UPDATE: i switched the 1 to an I but it still came up with the same error, the only thing that changed was that it now says I instead of 1 in the error. any other suggestions?
BTW, i am not updating jdk because im affraid that it wont work because the scripting language may have changed or something like that.

UPDATE AGAIN: i miss-read your answers, i put an i not an L. thanks for all of your help! it works perfectly now!

Comment: Can you try with JDK 6 and higher?

Comment: Jdk 3? Dude, you're lost in time more than 15 years! We're about to get Java 8. I would recommend you to install the latest jdk versiom and then start with your learning process.

Comment: Isn't JDK 3 like 13 years ago? Yeah, you should download Java 7 right away.

Answer (score 3):

It's `System.out.println("Java is Cool");` You were misspelling println.

Comment: Yes, and this is always a problem in so many books: 'l' and '1' look so similar ...

Answer (score 1):

The error is a typo. The method is `println` and you used `print1n`

Since you decided to learn Java, I would recommend to stop immediately and get the right tools. Use the [latest JDK](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/es/java/javase/downloads/index.html) and use an IDE like Netbeans or Eclipse for your development.

Answer (score 0):

You type wrong method

```
System.out.print1n();
```

You need

```
System.out.println();
```

instead.